# Error: numpy.ndarray object is not callable

Tags: numpy, multidimensional-array

**Error: numpy.ndarray object is not callable**

if type(input_batch) is np.ndarray:
            imshow(input_batch[0,:,:,0], target_batch[0,:,:], wmap_batch[0,:,:])

Comment: Do you have a `numpy` array named `imshow`?

Comment: Or something called `type`?  `xxx(...)` assumes `xxx` is a callable, a function.  But `xxx=np.array...` will produce this error by assigning an array to `xxx`, replacing the original value.  You have to figure out which variable has been misnamed or assigned wrongly.